# How to pass data in PageView.Builder from one pageview to another pageview - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose we are having some categories in page A and with the help pf the JSON post request i need to show the result of that in Page B, but how to pass data from page A as the ID from A to B to do the Post Request in page B.

Comment: it depends on what routing approach you're using, kindly tell us what was your approach.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: @MichaelSoliman I'm trying to build a news app using the pageview builder UI, if i swipe to the left(pageA) i should get the categories, if i select a category then it should navigate to pageB with the category details

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you're trying to achieve, but this is the simplest way to pass data to pages, this can be in a CategoryItem in your categories list, where each onPressed will navigate to the corresponding category.

```dart
ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text("Category $index"),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      // pass the category to PageB
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageB(category: categories[index])),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text("View"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: I needed to send data in the Pageview.builder not in Listview.builder

Comment: the list is for your categories, and you send it to another page right ? where do you want the pageview ?